# using IK functions in MecAnim

Tags: unity, animation, mecanim

The [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InverseKinematics.html) on how to use `IK` functions clearly states that *an Animator Controller with at least one animation for the character is required* and then Layers pane, IK pass, etc...

However, I cannot have an `animator controller` due to my using a motion-capture plug-in for Unity ([Xsens](https://www.xsens.com/) motion capture). If I add one, it starts off with that animation and then no live streaming of motion data...

I would still like to be able to use some `IK` functions though. I am not yet clear how they might help me, but basically I wanna apply the motion that, say, animates a character's right hand to another character's left hand, to create the impression that one character is responding to the other by copying his movements in a similar way. Is there any other way of using `IK` functions? Perhaps somehow in `LateUpdate`?

I do now know whether this is possible in `MecAnim` because maybe right and left hands and their bone structures (topology) are different.

Comment: Hey , sorry i am a bit confused here. Can you please tell me how is the plugin being used, I checked the site, but was not able to understand. Is it just to capture the motion and then use it later in the project. Or needs the motion capture in real time ??

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment. The plug-in is a set of scripts that map the motion data onto mecanim bone structure and animate a Unity character. You can download it here for free: [link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11338) Of course, you cannot run the motion capture software, because it requires a license, but just go into the scripts folder of the plug-in. Please let me know when you have done this, so I can tell you about the challenge more...

Comment: Hi, I don't know if it will work with your mocap plugin, but I'm able to override an animation by using IK functions (SetIKPositionWeight, etc...) in OnAnimatorIK(). It works really good. Hope this helps

Comment: Oh, ok you don't have an animator. Maybe your plugin has the same function ?

Comment: @FLX Thanks for your comments. My plug-in does have `private Animator animator;` which is accessed through `animator = model.GetComponent<Animator>();` in a function, and used for purposes such as `animator.GetBoneTransform(boneID);`. I just cannot add an actual `Animator Controller` not even an empty/blank one, for some reason. As soon as I do so, the plug-in stops working. Could you possibly see my other post which clarifies what I am trying to do: [link](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/how-to-modify-mecanim-bones-motion.362335/#post-2388222) Post title: _How to modify MecAnim Bones Motion_

Comment: I checked your thread. Except your plugin related code, it's not so different than my code, except you're not using OnAnimatorIK. I'm not a pro but I think you could try to use it to call your mapMecanimBones() function instead of update (if it's update because i don't see it in your thread)

Comment: @FLX Thanks for checking my thread. Do you mean updating my animation all in `OnAnimatorIK` instead of Unity's `Update`? I understand we need at least an empty `Animator Controller`. Can you disable yours and see if you can still use `IK` functions? I think the mentions of `animator` in scripts is not enough to be able to use `IK` methods... The scripts are here, downloadable for free. I have learned a lot by just going through them. You might like to take a look: [link](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/11338)

Comment: It looks like OnAnimatorIK only needs an Animator component, not AnimatorController. I'm currently at work so I can't test until tonight, but i'll come back if I find anything useful

Comment: @FLX  Many thanks for your help and comments. I will try this, and also hope to hear back from you if you found sth useful. Cheers

Comment: @FLX Hi there, I tried using void `OnAnimatorIK()` in a simple script that contains `private Animator animator;` as a class variable and also `animator = GetComponent<Animator>();` in the `Start` method, but without an actual `Animator Controller` that contains at least an `idle` animation, `IK` functions do not run. Sadly, I cannot have an `Animator Controller` because it makes my motion capture scripts useless, for some reason. I think I should start learning `Final IK` as I understand it would not require an `Animator Controller`

Comment: Hi, just saw this : "The Animator component requires a reference to an Animator Controller which defines which animation clips to use".
You should ask xens, maybe there are ways to override the controller using a weight parameter, like IK functions ?

Comment: Thank you. I have already asked them, but was told: The intern who wrote the plug-in no longer works here, so your best bet is learning the code in the plug-in scripts and figuring it out yourself. Which I have done so, though cannot figure this out. I am happy to send you the scripts which are probably simple to you. I am also now posting a different question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33895406/swapping-animations-of-mecanim-bones) which might help me round this. Please take a look if you have a minute. Thanks